# mapping data from json array for multiple data gives error in react and webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, webpack

I am trying to map data from a json array as follows

```
{movies.map((item. i) => (
  <RecentItem item={item} index={i} />
))}
```

when it displays it works but when I hover over the data it hides the next data
[image when hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvsB9.png)
the image when not hovered [when not hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAkey.png)
what is wrong below is my styling for the hover

```
    &:hover {
        width: 372px;
        height: 372px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -150px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.07);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.07);
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

pls if you need more codes let me know, thanks

Comment: What is the expected behavior when you hover?

Comment: It is supposed to give the hovered result without changing the positions of any of the other image just like netflix